# unable to install prisma client

Tags: postgresql, docker, nestjs, prisma

npm install  @prisma/client
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/@nestjs%2Ftcesting - Not found
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404  '@nestjs/tcesting@^10.0.0' is not in this registry.
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\Sibelle Djumeghe\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2024-02-22T09_14_08_074Z-debug-0.log

npx prisma migrate dev --name init

expected result:

```
prisma
```

├── dev.db
├── migrations
│   └── 20201207100915_init
│       └── migration.sql
└── schema.prisma

npm install @prisma/client

expected result:

generate prisma client but got an error

npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/@nestjs%2Ftcesting - Not found
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404  '@nestjs/tcesting@^10.0.0' is not in this registry.
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\Sibelle Djumeghe\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2024-02-22T09_14_08_074Z-debug-0.log

Comment: Welcome to SO ! Your question lack of formating and may be improve, please see: [Editing Help]( https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Answer (score 0):

you must first install prisma, before installing prisma client:

```
npm install prisma --save-dev
npm install @prisma/client
```

the nestjs documentation explain this [how to install and use prisma](https://docs.nestjs.com/recipes/prisma)